# How many collision and broadcast domains are in the diagram

Tags: ethernet

I always have trouble understanding what creates what i know every hub is a collision. my guess is 1 broadcast 2 collision. [image]

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: No its optional work.

Comment: Every switch port is a collision domain.

Comment: so theres 3 collisions and 1 broadcast domain?

Comment: The first switch has three connections, one of which it shares with the second switch, and the second switch has two connections, one of which is shared with the first switch. Every link connected to a switch port is a collision domain.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the switches are vlan capable, there is one broadcast domain per vlan (if the vlans are trunked between the 2 switches , otherwise one broadcast domain per vlan per switch.
If not vlan capable,  there is one single broadcast domain.

For the collision domain, the topology is very poorly drawn but I assume that each set of 3 computers is connected to a different port of the hub or switch above it. In that case I count 6 collision domains:

- CD1: Port 1 of the top switch, the hub connected to it and everything connected to that hub
- CD2: Port 2 of the top switch, the hub connected to it and everything connected to that hub
- CD3: The link between the two switches
- CD4, CD5, CD6: Each port of the right-hand-side switch that has a host connected to it is a separate collision domain.

Edit1: reading [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_domain) it seems that I had a slightly different view on what a collision domain is, so if you go by wikipedia then items 3-6 in my list above are only collision domains if those ports are operating in half duplex mode. If they are in full duplex  then only items 1&2 are collision domains.

Edit2: to further clarify, my initial thought (before edit1) can be visualised like this:
[image: topology1]

But if you consider the wikipedia definition of collision domain and if you assume that the switchports that are not connected to a hub, are operating in full duplex, then it becomes this:
[image: topology2]

Comment: I don't object to people downvoting, but in this case I'm really genuinely interested in hearing why.

Comment: I am really unable to understand why this got downvoted. Kudos for the detailed and illustrated explanation. This answer is 100% correct and also tackles the ambiguity in the original diagram.

Comment: It isn't really the question of whether you ascribe to the wikipedia definition, it's the question of how the network is designed.  If those are 10Mbit/100Mbit switch ports, they *could* be operated in half-duplex mode, and thus create a collision domain.  If they're 1Gbit or higher there is no half-duplex mode, so ports would never create a collision domain.

Answer (score -1):

regarding to ***HUB***, all the devices attached to the hub are in  ***one BC domain*** and ***one collision domain***.regarding to the ***switch***, each ***port*** is ***collision domain*** and each ***VLAN*** is a ***BC domain***.SO
as shown

[image]

we have 4 collision domains, but the number of the BC domains is very depend. for example if sw1 and sw2 run same vlan on all ports so all this network run in single BC domain.

Comment: If you consider SW2 to have 3 hosts connected to it (but I agree the drawing is a bit ambiguous in that regard) then I think this answer just says the same as my (earlier) answer. In addition, depending on how you define collision domain (and depending on whether all switch ports are operating in full duplex) CD_3 and CD_4 may or may not be considered collision domains (cfr. the edit of my answer).

Comment: And there is a small nuance in the "each vlan is a BC domain" since that depends on what vlans are trunked (e.g. if you have vlan1 on SW1 and vlan2 on SW2 but vlan2 is not allowed on the SW1-SW2 trunk then you actually have *two* vlan2 BC domains).

Comment: L2 vlan is separate L2 switch and any type of broadcast can't leave it so we have no confusion here. whenever this L2 vlan is extended this vlan will be considered as BC domain. regarding to collision as any one can define it is a feild where collision could occur, regarding to switch each port is separate collision domain thanks to CSMA/CD mechanism

Comment: I see I made a typo in my previous comment, what I meant was:  there is a small nuance in the "each vlan is a BC domain" since that depends on what vlans are trunked (e.g. if you have vlan2 on SW1 and vlan2 on SW2 but vlan2 is not allowed on the SW1-SW2 trunk then you actually have *two* vlan2 BC domains).

Comment: So by your definition "collision as any one can define it is a feild where collision *could* occur", CD_3 and CD_4 are collision domains because there *could* be collisions if the ports are operating in half duplex?

Comment: I still don't understand why this answer gets an upvote and mine got a downvote because they are essentially saying the same thing (the part before my "Edit"), the only differences are that I added some detail about vlans, and we interpreted the drawing differently (Gadeliow sees only one host connected to SW2, I see 3 hosts connected there, so obviously I see 2 more potential collision domains).

Answer (score -1):

3 collision domains for 1st switch and "n-1" collision domains(It will share one collision domain of first switch) for "n" connections of 2nd switch AND all the devices are in a single broadcast domain.